# CefSharp - Colar texto do clipboard em input no evento onclick

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Tenho um `input` dentro de um `Iframe` em uma página `.html` em `https` com o evento `onclick` chamando uma função:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="TXT_PROTOCOLO" placeholder="Clique para colar o protocolo" onclick="pasteClipboard(this)" />
```

Sendo a função `pasteClipboard`:

```
function pasteClipboard(e)
{
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text =>
    {
        console.log('Clipboard text: ', text);
        e.value = text;
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

O código acima funciona normalmente no Chrome, mas não no CefSharp.
Tentei modificar/adicionar algumas propriedades da variável do tipo `BrowserSettings` na criação da variável do tipo `ChromiumWebBrowser`, *i.e.*:

```
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("startupUrl"))
{
    // Adicionando outras configurações ao browser
    BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings
    {
        JavascriptAccessClipboard = CefState.Enabled,
        JavascriptDomPaste = CefState.Enabled
    }
};
```

Pensei que habilitando `JavascriptAccessClipboard` e `JavascriptDomPaste` para o navegador fosse resolver o problema (parece autoexplicativo), mas sempre é expelido no `console` um `DOMException`:

[image: DOMException]

Já tive problemas em habilitar o acesso ao microfone, mesmo utilizando a flag `enable-media-stream` e só consegui resolver quando coloquei o executável na lista de aplicativos confiáveis do `Kaspersky Endpoint Security for Windows`. Então acredito que não tem a ver com o antivírus ou talvez devo utilizar outra forma de colar o texto do `clipboard` no `input`.

Comment: tem alguma informação na exception ? já testou em outro computador sem o kaspersky ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Eu só consegui descobrir que o antivírus estava bloqueando o microfone quando testei em uma máquina de teste. O comportamento persistiu mesmo nessa máquina sem o Kaspersky. Já a exception expelida é sempre sem detalhes (vou editar o post com uma imagem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma alternativa ao problema a partir [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344799/how-to-get-clipboard-data-in-non-main-thread) resposta. A ideia é passar o conteúdo do `clipboard` do C# para o Javascript utilizando a classe [Clipboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netframework-4.8).

Criei um método parecido com o do link acima:

```
public string GetClipboardText()
{
    string clipboardData = string.Empty;
    Thread staThread = new Thread( delegate () { clipboardData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text); });

    staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    staThread.Start();
    staThread.Join();

    return clipboardData.Trim();
}
```

Simplesmente retornar `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)` ou `Clipboard.GetText()` não funciona, sempre retornava uma `string` vazia. A alternativa foi colocar essa chamada numa `thread`e então retornar o valor.

E no Javascript:

```
function pasteClipboard(e)
{
    cefSession.getClipboardText().then(r => e.value = r);
}
```